# Math.net numerics DenseMatrix backward compatibility

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

Is DenseMatrix from version 3.2.3.2 not comatible with 2.6.x.x version ?

Is there any substitute for creating DenseMatrix from two dimensional array ?

```
var xDense = new DenseMatrix(double[,] xData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found static method in DenseMatrix to create from array,

```
var xReal = DenseMatrix.OfArray(xData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the static method [DenseColumnMajorMatrixStorage.OfArray(T[,] array)](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Storage/DenseColumnMajorMatrixStorage%601.htm#OfArray) and then use the [`DenseMatrix` constructor](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double/DenseMatrix.htm#.ctor) that uses `DenseColumnMajorMatrixStorage<T>`.

```
double[,] xData = ...;
var storage = DenseColumnMajorMatrixStorage<double>.OfArray(xData);
var xDense = new DenseMatrix(storage);
```

Comment: Thanks, I found another way. Answer below. Any ideas which option is faster ?

Comment: I'd bet that `DenseMatrix.OfArray` calls `DenseColumnMajorMatrixStorage<T>.OfArray` so they are equivalent in speed. `DenseMatrix.OfArray` is cleaner though!

Comment: Thanks, then using `DenseMatrix.OfArray`